# Remove border from table cell

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I have a table structure which is dynamically generated. There is a tricky styling to the table table.

I have added border top and right to the direct table, what I need is to remove/manipulate with border color for first and last `td` of the `table`.

If you can see my fiddle, I need to wrap the orange colored table with outline of grey color. At the same time the border of 1px to the `td` should remain the same.

If I try giving the border top to the cell then white border is collapsing.

**CSS:**

```
.table_main {
    border-top: 3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
    border-right: 3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}

.table_main td {
    background: #ff9d26;
    border-right: solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px
}

.left {
    background: #fff !important;
    border-right: 3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
    border-bottom: 0 !important
}

.noborder {
    background: #fff !important;
}

.bottom{
    background: #fff !important;
    border-top: 3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}

.top{
    border-top: 1px solid #fff  
}
```

Please check the **[DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/IZAFAmI/2/)**

**P.S - I dont want to change the structure of the html because it is auto generated table code. And no pseudo classes since it is not supported in IE8 and below. I need this to be proper in IE7+**

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/IZAFAmI/7)

change your CSS classes like this:

```
<table class="table_main" width="400" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="top">
        <td class="left">x</td>
        <td>vb</td>
        <td>X</td>
        <td class="right">g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">2</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td class="right">x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">3</td>
        <td>v</td>
        <td>v</td>
        <td class="right">d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom">
        <td class="left">4</td>
        <td>r</td>
        <td>r</td>
        <td class="right">x</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and use this CSS:

```
.table_main {
}

.table_main td {
    background: #ff9d26;
    border-right: solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px
}

.left, .bottom td {
    background: #fff !important;
}

.right, .left {
    border-right: 3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}

.top td {
    border-top :3px solid #d6d6d6; 
}

.bottom td {
    border-top: 3px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.bottom .left {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none !important
}

.top .left {
    border-top: none;
}

.bottom .right {
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention.. I can not use pseudo class since it is no widely supported by IE versions

Comment: Yes I can add classes

Comment: on first row top white border is missing. I need that also, as it is in my demo

Comment: i think it is better that you forget about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
position:relative; top:-3px; padding-top:3px; /* to adjust the nudge */
```

to the class `.left`

And

```
position:relative; right:-3px; padding-right:3px; /* to adjust the nudge */
```

To the class `.bottom`

This should work in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table_main" width="400" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="left">how to remove top border from this cell?</td>
    <td class="top">vb</td>
    <td class="top">X</td>
    <td class="topRightCorner">g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">2</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td class="right">x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="left">3</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td class="right">d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noborder">4</td>
    <td class="bottom">r</td>
    <td class="bottom">r</td>
    <td class="bottom">how to remove right border from this cell?</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

and with this CSS:

```
.table_main{

}
.table_main td{
    background:#ff9d26;
    border-right:solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    padding:1px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px
}
.left{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
    border-bottom:0 !important
}
.noborder{
    background:#fff !important;
}
.bottom{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}
.top{
    border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}
.right{
  border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}
.topRightCorner{
  border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important;
  border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo first (I've tested this in IE7,8,9,10 as well as latest Chrome and Firefox):

http://jsbin.com/ImEvAGoJ/5

I've used a combination of `border` and `box-shadow` to achieve the double border effect. Of course `box-shadow` is not supported in IE8 and lower, so I had to use the equivalent `DropShadow` filter ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Example:

```
.table_main .top.right {
  box-shadow: 1px 0 white, 4px 0 #d6d6d6, 
              0 -1px white, 0 -4px #d6d6d6,
              1px -1px white, 4px -4px #d6d6d6;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=-1, Color='#00ffffff', Positive='true'),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, Color='#00ffffff', Positive='true'),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=-1, OffY=0, Color='#00ffffff', Positive='true'),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=1, OffY=0, Color='#00ffffff', Positive='true'),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=-3, Color='#00d6d6d6', Positive='true'),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=3, OffY=0, Color='#00d6d6d6', Positive='true');
}
```

Note that the grey `box-shadow` is `4px` wide because it overlaps the `1px` white shadow.

Also, this assumes that you can change the classes on your table which I think you said you can do in one of your comments above.

Basically, use `outside` class for all cells that are out side of your grey border, `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` classes for top row, left column, bottom row, and right column cells respectively. Your HTML should look like this:

```
<table class="table_main" width="400" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">how to remove top border from this cell?</td>
    <td class="top left">vb</td>
    <td class="top">X</td>
    <td class="top right">g</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">2</td>
    <td class="left">z</td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td class="right">x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">3</td>
    <td class="left bottom">v</td>
    <td class="bottom">v</td>
    <td class="bottom right">d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="outside">4</td>
    <td class="outside">r</td>
    <td class="outside">r</td>
    <td class="outside">how to remove right border from this cell?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:** here are screenshots from IE7 on Vista, IE8 on WinXP, and IE8 on Win7:

[image: Screenshot from IE7 on Vista]

[image: Screenshot from IE8 on WinXP]

[image]

Comment: This is not taking grey borders in ie7 and 8

Comment: @Sowmya that's strange. I've just added screenshots for IE7 and 8. What browser/OS versions are you testing on?

Comment: @Sowmya Could you tell me more? so I can help :) This might be the only way to solve your problem with the requirements you have, and it should/does work in IE7,8. Are you using IE compatibility modes? or do you have multiple versions on IE installed on the same version of windows? Either way I'd consider testing on machines with single/full browser version per OS (as opposed to something like multipleIE).

Comment: I have just added a screenshot from IE8 on Windows 7. As you can see the grey borders are there. For IE testing, I recommend using the free VMs provided on http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine solutions provided by Morpheus and Suraj Naik.

IE 8 supports first-child but it doesn't support last-child, so you can replace

```
table > tbody > tr:last-child > td:last-child
```

with

```
tr+tr+tr+tr td+td+td+td.bottom {
```

to reach the last cell.

For IE7, you can add the code provided by Suraj Naik in conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

You can find full CSS below:

```
<style>
.table_main{
        border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
        border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important;
}
.table_main td{
    background:#ff9d26;
    border-right:solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    padding:1px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px
}
.left{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
    border-bottom:0 !important;
}
.noborder{
    background:#fff !important;
}
.bottom{
    background:#fff !important;
    border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important;
}
.top{
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child
{
  margin-top: -3px;
  float: left;
}

tr+tr+tr+tr td+td+td+td.bottom {
  margin-right: -3px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.left{
    position:relative; top:-3px; padding-top:3px; /* to adjust the nudge */
}
.bottom{
    position:relative; right:-3px; padding-right:3px; /* to adjust the nudge */
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
.table_main{
}
.table_main td{
    background:#ff9d26;
    border-right:solid 1px #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    padding:1px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px
}
.left, .bottom td{
    background:#fff !important;
}
.right, .left{
  border-right:3px solid #d6d6d6 !important; 
}
.top td{
  border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6; 
}
.bottom td{
  border-top:3px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.bottom .left{
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none !important
}
.top .left{
  border-top:none;
}
.bottom .right{
  border-right:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the td classes further **remove the border styling from the table {}** and apply a class name to the elements you wish to receive the grey border.

```
td.top { border-top: 3px solid #D6D6D6; }
```

Then add another class for right border styling:

```
td.rightBorder { border-right: 3px solid #D6D6D6; }
```

Make sure to add both class names to the cell that contains the 'g'.